# In jqgrid how to check checkbox on row select?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the below code for my [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options), I want to select a row and the corresponding checkbox to be checked, if i click on the same row again, the checkbox should be disabled, how can i achieve this? I am also providing a snapshot.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
         $('#configDiv').empty();
            $('<div width="100%">')
            .attr('id','configDetailsGrid')
            .html('<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>')       
            .appendTo('#configDiv');    

            var grid = jQuery("#list1");

            grid.jqGrid({

              datastr : xml,
              datatype: 'xmlstring',
              colNames:['cfgId','','Name', 'Host', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By',''],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
                  {name:'',index:'', width:15, align:"right",edittype:'checkbox',formatter: "checkbox",editoptions: { value:"True:False"},editable:true,formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                  {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
              ],
              pager : '#gridpager',
              rowNum:10,
              scrollOffset:0,
              height: 'auto',

              autowidth:true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              xmlReader: {
                  root : "list",
                  row: "com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },
              onSelectRow: function(id,status){
                  var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                  configid = rowData['cfgId'];
                  configname=rowData['cfgName'];
                  configdesc=rowData['cfgDesc'];
                  configenv=rowData['cfgType'];

                  if(status==true)
                  {

                  }

                  rowChecked=1;
                  currentrow=id;
                  },
              onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
                  if(index==2)
                  {

                        $(xmlDoc).find('list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo').each(function()
                        {
                            //alert($(this).find('cfgId').text()+" "+configid);
                            if($(this).find('cfgId').text()==configid)  
                            {
                                configname=$(this).find('cfgName').text(); 
                                configdesc=$(this).find('cfgDesc').text();
                                configenv=$(this).find('cfgType').text();
                                filename=$(this).find('fileName').text();
                                updatedate=$(this).find('updateDate').text();
                                absolutepath=$(this).find('absolutePath').text();
                                productname=productMap[$(this).find('productId').text()];
                            }
                        });

                  }
               }

            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

[image]

**Updated**

my onSelectRow

```
var ch =  jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
if(ch) {
  jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
} else {
      jQuery(this).find('#'+id+'input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);                       
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To your **onSelectRow** function add:

```
var ch =  jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
if(ch) {
      jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
} else {
      jQuery(this).find('#'+id+'input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);                       
}
```

**Edit:**
Put this at the and of your JS code in order to run selection when clicking a checkbox

```
$("#list1").find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).change( function(){
        var colid = $(this).parents('tr:last').attr('id');
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $("#list1").jqGrid('setSelection', colid );
           $(this).prop('checked',true);
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/tr5RA/14/

Comment: @WooDzu: it says Object dosen't support this property or method, please see my updated question

Comment: if you are not using newest jQuery, change .prop() to .attr()

Comment: sorry, I wasn't on computer for a while.  Is it working for you now?

Comment: @WooDzu: ya it is working.. also if you could help me again. I need to jqGrid to select the current row if checkbox is cilcked, can you help me with that too [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466750/how-to-select-jqgrid-row-on-checkbox-click) is the link? Thanks