# How to select jqGrid row on checkbox click?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Below is my code for jqGrid, i'd like to select row or highlight the current row, when i `check` a particular checkbox inside jqgrid row. right now `onSelectRow` I am making the checkbox get checked.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
         $('#configDiv').empty();
            $('<div width="100%">')
            .attr('id','configDetailsGrid')
            .html('<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>')       
            .appendTo('#configDiv');    

            var grid = jQuery("#list1");

            grid.jqGrid({

              datastr : xml,
              datatype: 'xmlstring',
              colNames:['cfgId','','Name', 'Host', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By',''],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
                  {name:'',index:'', width:15, align:"right",edittype:'checkbox',formatter: "checkbox",editoptions: { value:"True:False"},editable:true,formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                  {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
              ],
              pager : '#gridpager',
              rowNum:10,
              scrollOffset:0,
              height: 'auto',

              autowidth:true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              xmlReader: {
                  root : "list",
                  row: "com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },
              onSelectRow: function(id,status){
                  var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                  configid = rowData['cfgId'];
                  configname=rowData['cfgName'];
                  configdesc=rowData['cfgDesc'];
                  configenv=rowData['cfgType'];

                  if(status==true)
                  {

                  }

                  rowChecked=1;
                  currentrow=id;
                  },
              onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
                  if(index==2)
                  {

                        $(xmlDoc).find('list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo').each(function()
                        {
                            //alert($(this).find('cfgId').text()+" "+configid);
                            if($(this).find('cfgId').text()==configid)  
                            {
                                configname=$(this).find('cfgName').text(); 
                                configdesc=$(this).find('cfgDesc').text();
                                configenv=$(this).find('cfgType').text();
                                filename=$(this).find('fileName').text();
                                updatedate=$(this).find('updateDate').text();
                                absolutepath=$(this).find('absolutePath').text();
                                productname=productMap[$(this).find('productId').text()];
                            }
                        });

                  }
               }

            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

So how would I select current row on checkbox selected?

Comment: hi, have you tried my code yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this at the and of your JS code in order to run selection when clicking a checkbox

```
$("#list1").find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).change( function(){
        var colid = $(this).parents('tr:last').attr('id');
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $("#list1").jqGrid('setSelection', colid );
           $(this).prop('checked',true);
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

example UPDATED AGAIN: http://jsfiddle.net/vCWNP/

**edit:**
this also should be done every time a new row is added.
let me know if something else is to be fixed ;]

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me, that you could solve your problem very easy. What you try to do is already implemented in the jqGrid. If you **remove** the column `name:'',index:''` which has **empty `name`, which is NOT PERMITTED** and include an additional jqGrid parameter `multiselect:true` all will work like you as need.

Comment: Where should i add `multiselect:true`? Also I have CRUD, so when i click update button and there is more than 1 checkbox selected, it should prompt user, ie., it should not go for update, how can i achieve this in this case?

Comment: @Ricky: You should include `multiselect:true` on the same place of the jqGrid definition where you use all other [jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) like `datatype`, `rowNum` and so on. You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717969/jqgrid-multiselect-behavior-when-pressing-special-key/3719637#3719637) some demos how multiselect can be used. About your second question with update button I am not sure that I correct understand what you mean. Probably you can explain what you need more detailed? Which editing mode you plan to use?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do that:

```
jQuery(".jqgrow td input").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).click(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', $(this).parents('tr').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

on  your **onSelectRow** function add:

```
var flag = jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
if(flag){
      jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'red' )// row will be in red if checkbox is selected, you have to find out the current row here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `you have to find out the current row here
` where do i need to use current row?

Comment: @Ricky: i am not familar with jqgrid, but the code which i have written will give you checked checkbox  in every row(i suppose), now it's you, who have to find row(this.closet('<tr>').css(), something like this) and apply css to that row...sorry to not answer at your context. :(