# Highlight row when the checkbox is true

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Can Some one help me, I have a jqgrid and I want to highlight the row if the checkbox is true, thanks!!

[image]

this is what i want to make in this project...

```
function loadjqGrid(jsonGridData){
    var xaxis=1300
    var yaxis = $(document).height();
    yaxis = yaxis-500;
    getGrids();     
    $("#maingrid").jqGrid({
        url:'models/mod.quoservicetypedetails.php?ACTION=view',
        mtype: 'POST',
        datatype: 'xml',
        colNames:getColumnNames(jsonGridData),
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'TypeID', index:'TypeID', width:350,hidden:true, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,
            edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:getTypeID()},editrules: { edithidden: true}},  
            {name:'Order1', index:'Order1', width:80, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                  
            {name:'Order2', index:'Order2', width:80, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}}, 
            {name:'Order3', index:'Order3', width:80, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                      
            {name:'Description', index:'Description', width:140, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,
            edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                    
            {name:'Notes', index:'Notes', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}}, 
            {name:'Measure', index:'Measure', width:80, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true, edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                  
            {name:'UnitPrice', index:'UnitPrice', width:100, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:false,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},  
            {name:'Remarks', index:'Remarks', width:140, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}}, 
            {name:'UnitCost', index:'UnitCost', width:100, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},     
            {name:'Service', index:'Service', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}}, 
            //If the GroupHeader is true the row background is yellow
            {name:'GroupHeader', index:'GroupHeader', width:100, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,formatter:'checkbox', edittype:'checkbox', type:'select', editoptions:{value:"1:0"}}, 
            {name:'IsGroup', index:'IsGroup', width:80, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,formatter:'checkbox', edittype:'checkbox', type:'select', editoptions:{value:"1:0"}}, 
        ],
        viewrecords: true,  
        rowNum:20,
        sortname: 'id', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: yaxis,
        pager : '#gridpager',
        recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
        emptyrecords: "No records to view",
        loadtext: "Loading...",
        pgtext : "Page {0} of {1}",         
        height: yaxis,
        width: xaxis,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        multiselect: true,
        editurl:'models/mod.quoservicetypedetails.php?ACTION=edit'
    }); 
}
```

How could I do this? Can someone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466750/how-to-select-jqgrid-row-on-checkbox-click

Comment: [link]https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Gda0KxFtUiM/T6uDOgi_YjI/AAAAAAAAAGw/Cdn74czGJ7A/w1519-h449-k/sample.JPG

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575634/315935) one good way how you can implement the highlighting.

Version 4.3.2 of jqGrid has new feature - `rowattr` callback (see [my original suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/introduce-rowattr-jqgrid-like-cellattr-but-for-setting-attributes-on-tr-element-instead-of-td/#p26208)), which was introduced especially for cases like yours. It allows you to highlight some rows of grid *during filling* of the grid. To have the best performance advantage you should use `gridview: true` additionally. By the way **I recommend you to use `gridview: true` in all jqGrids**.

The usage of `rowattr` callback is very easy:

```
gridview: true,
rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (rd.GroupHeader === "1") { // verify that the testing is correct in your case
        return {"class": "myAltRowClass"};
    }
}
```

The CSS class `myAltRowClass` should define background color of highlighted rows.

The corresponding demo you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm):

[image]

Because in your demo you need just highlight and not select the rows I didn't used `multiselect: true` in my demo. In case of `multiselect: true` it works exactly in the same way.

At the end of my answer I would like to recommend you to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935). The feature will make your code shorter, more readable and easy to maintain. What you need to do is the following:

- you can include common or the most frequently used settings from column definitions in `cmTemplete`. In your case it could be

```js
cmTemplate: {align: 'center', sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80}
```

- then you can define some variables which describe common properties which you use frequently in some columns. For example:

```js
var myCheckboxTemplate = {formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', type: 'select',
        editoptions: {value: "1:0"}},
    myTextareaTemplate = {edittype: "textarea",
        editoptions: {size: "30", maxlength: "30"}};
```

- after that you can use `myCheckboxTemplate` and `myTextareaTemplate` inside of `colModel` which will reduced in your case to the following

```js
colModel: [
    {name: 'TypeID', index: 'TypeID', width: 350, hidden: true, edittype: "select",
        editoptions: {value: getTypeID()}, editrules: { edithidden: true}},
    {name: 'Order1', index: 'Order1', template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Order2', index: 'Order2', template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Order3', index: 'Order3', template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 140, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Notes', index: 'Notes', width: 120, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Measure', index: 'Measure', template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'UnitPrice', index: 'UnitPrice', width: 100, editable: false, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 140, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'UnitCost', index: 'UnitCost', width: 100, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    {name: 'Service', index: 'Service', width: 120, template: myTextareaTemplate},
    //If the GroupHeader is true the row background is yellow
    {name: 'GroupHeader', index: 'GroupHeader', width: 100, template: myCheckboxTemplate},
    {name: 'IsGroup', index: 'IsGroup', template: myCheckboxTemplate}
],
cmTemplate: {align: 'center', sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80},
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help once again Oleg! I do have a "sub-question" which I think is related to this question. Can you please [**check it out here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841588/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-grouping-header)?

Comment: @FastTrack: You question is very good! I think the best way will be to change the code of `groupingRender` to call `rowattr`, but I will try to prepare some solution for existing version of jqGrid. I'll come back to your question later (probably at the weekend).