# Percentage sorting on a column in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Have the following in my jqGrid:

```js
colModel.push({ name: 'pcc2008-2007', index: 'pcc0807', width: 100, align: "Right",
    sorttype: "float", formatter: "number", resizable: false,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return percentageChange(rowObject['vol08'], rowObject['vol07'], 4);
    }
});
```

The formatter works perfectly, returning a value (with a prefixing %) at the end, but when I come to click on the column header on the grid, the results are not sorted what-so-ever.

I've added an "unformatter" function, which simply replaces the "%" with nothing to see if that produced the correct sort, but likewise the sort just doesn't implement correctly at all.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

** EDIT **

```js
function percentageChange(endYear, startYear, duration) {
    var p1 = Math.abs((endYear - startYear) / Math.abs(startYear) * 100);
    if (p1 == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || p1 == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) { return '0'; }
    if (isNaN(p1)) { return '0'; }
    else { return Math.round(p1 * 100) / 100; }
}
```

** EDI2 **

Entire jqGrid calling here:

```js
$("#list2").jqGrid({
    datastr: formattedBrandData,
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    colModel: colModel,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 1000,
    loadonce: true,
    sortable:  true,
    gridview: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 100,
    gridComplete: function (index, colindex, sortorder) {

        var aaa = $("#list2").jqGrid('getRowData');
        formattedBrandData = aaa;
        drawChart();


        var rowIDs = jQuery("#list2").getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < rowIDs.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (i == 0) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour1'); }
            if (i == 1) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour2'); }
            if (i == 2) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour3'); }
            if (i == 3) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour4'); }
            if (i == 4) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour5'); }
            if (i == 5) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour6'); }
            if (i == 6) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour7'); }
            if (i == 7) { var trElement = jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2')); trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content'); trElement.addClass('resultsColour8'); }
        }
    },

    loadComplete: function () {

    },


    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) {
            return obj;
        },
        onComplete: function (data, response) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't define the same property of the same object more as once. In the code which you posted the property `formatter` is defined one as `"number"` and once as `function (...) {...}`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should better use

```js
formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: {suffix: '%'}, sorttype: 'currency'
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortablepercent.htm):

[image]

**UPDATED**: There are some problems in the code which you posted.

The first one is the `gridComplete` callback which will be called by jqGrid. jqGrid never call `gridComplete` with additional parameters, so `index`, `colindex` and `sortorder` parameters of your callback will be always `undefined`. You should remove the parameters.

The second problem is design problem. You use `datatype: "jsonstring"` together with `datastr: formattedBrandData` which provide the data. The data will be read *once* and the data will be saved in the internal `data` array with the same properties as the `name` property of the `colModel`. So it will be more effective and more easy **to fill `'pcc2008-2007'` property inside of `formattedBrandData` array**. You will calculate the value **once** and will just use the `float` retult of the calculation. Later you can use predefined `currency` formatter (see my answer above) directly only to add `%` at the end of the float value.

If you use some local datatype (inclusive `datatype: "jsonstring"`) you should never use `index` other as `name`. It's better just remove any `index` definition from the `colModel` in the case it will be used the value from `name` property. Different values of `name` and `index` are supported and can be helpful only in case of `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` where the server code in responsible for the sorting of data.

You should reduce the number of changes of the grid (or any other changes of the data on the HTML page) inside of `gridComplete` or `loadComplete` whenever it's possible. In case of one change of one element the web browser have to recalculate position of **all** other existing elements on the page. So the changes of elements on the page could be expensive. On the other side the usage of `gridview: true` together with formatters, `rowattr` callback (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/284)) or `cellattr` allows to modify the HTML fragment of the grid *before* it will be placed on the page. In the way you get the best performance. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for the corresponding code example where `rowattr` callback is demonstrated.

The last remark about the performance. The code `jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2'))` is slowly as `jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i])`. The reason is that `jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i])` just use `id` which is indexed. So it works quickly. On the other side the code `jQuery("#" + rowIDs[i], $('#list2'))` uses explicit context which don't allows to use the index *of the HTML page*. So the simple scan will be used for the implementation which will be slow.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, that does make things a bit clearer, but what I don't understand or see in the documention is to how to add the 'currency' formatter into a formatter function (my function performs some calculations to return the value, it's not taken from the json reader source)

Comment: @JasonMHirst: You should **either** use one from [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) (like 'currency', 'number' etc) **or** define you custom formatter: `formatter` and `unformat` as functions (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)). If your case I see no sense to use custom formatter because predefined 'currency' formatter can be just used (see the code of my demo).

Comment: @JasonMHirst: If you do can't use 'currency' formatter because of non-standard input (if you can't change the format of data returned from the server) you should just define `unformat` function or define your custom `sorttype` function. The most problem is that you posted too few code. The code of `percentageChange` function is uncler. It's unclear whether you have local data or not, whether the *sorting* are implemented on your server part or on the client side.

Comment: Oleg, I see what you're saying.  Have changed my original to show the "percentageChange" function (although this is obviously subject to change to the correct formula)

Comment: @JasonMHirst: You don't answered on all my questions. First: you wrote `I've added an "unformatter" function`, but not included the corresponding code. Do you defined `unformat` function or the function with another name (like `unformatter`)? Do use use `datatype: 'local'` or get the data directly from the server? Is the client code is really responsible for the sorting? I don't understend why you use `'vol08'` and `'vol07'` property instead of *one* value which correcponds the result of `percentageChange`? Which sense has to make the calculation in the formatter?

Comment: @JasonMHirst: Do you get the data `'vol08'` and `'vol07'` **on the server** and post it back to the client **only for jqGrid** of you use the `'vol08'` and `'vol07'` somewhere else in the client code?

Comment: Well those values are used on the grid for calculations and are also pass as variables to be used throughout the entire page too.

Comment: again, that's a LOT to digest, so will go through what you've said one by one.  The only problem I forsee is that, like I mentioned, I have a number of columns which can NOT be calculated on the server, but rather dynamic calculations from checkboxes on the webpage.  I'll re-think, and go through some more examples, I'm sure what I want to do is entirely possible, but you're right, maybe I need to rethink the overall picture first.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @JasonMHirst: You are welcome! You can just include a `for` loop which goes through all the items of `formattedBrandData` array and set **once** the new property `'pcc2008-2007'` (or better to use `pcc0807` probably). In the way you call `percentageChange` once instead of making the same calculations every time. Moreover during sorting *over the page boundaries* you really need to have the values *saved* in the internal `data` array. Alternatively you can use `sorttype` as function, but it will work slowly.