# JqGrid - How to dynamically Highlight the color of multiple rows

Tags: jqgrid, colors, background, row

How to change the color of multiple rows dynamically based on the condition using JSON. I got one script which will works if we use "multiselect: true" as an option. But i don't want to display check box in my grid. So by using multiselect as false, how can i achieve ...

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

It not clear what you mean exactly under "based on the condition using JSON". Probably you mean that you load remote data from the server in JSON format (`datatype: "json"`) and you want to change background color of some rows based on the some condition from the loaded data. The best way in the case would be the usage of `rowattr` callback of jqGrid. The callback `rowattr` will be called after the data for the row of the grid is prepared. So you have access to the data of every column of the row and can verify any condition to decide whether the row should be highlighted. If you would return for example `return {"class": "myHighlightClass"};` from the `rowattr` on some rows that corresponding `<tr>` element (the row) receive additional attribute `class="myHighlightClass"`.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for the corresponding code example.