# Making a row bold, changing background color - dwr

Tags: jqgrid, dwr

I have a jqgrid which has been loaded from dwr call. It is a dynamic table. In POJO I set 3 status and generate dynamic checkbox.

This is my pojo code.

```
   private String cBox;

   public String cBox()
   {

    if (style() == D)
    {
        return i l create checkbox here;
    }
    else if (style() == E)
    {
        return checkbox will be created ;
    }
    else if (getStatusFlag() == F)
    {
        return checkbox will be created;
    }


    return cBox;
}
```

I load jqgrid like this.

```
colNames : ['Code no.', 'Title' ],
                colModel : [{
                    name : 'code_no',
                    index : 'code_no',
                    width : '100%',
                    sorttype : 'text',
                    align : 'left'
                },
                                    {
                    name : 'title',
                    index : 'title',
                    width : '100%',
                    sorttype : 'text',
                    align : 'left'
                }]
```

I want to make the entire row bold, if the style is D and I want to make the background color of the row blue when the color is E. How should I customize the jqgrid row ?

Comment: So if a cell value is of a type then you want the row to be in bold?

Comment: @Mark yeah!! I have to change the data bold or have to change the background color

Answer (score 3):

The following function will examine each column cell value and if the TestValue is matching add the class to the row.

```
    rowattr: function (rd) {
           if (rd.ColumnName == TestValue) { return {"class": "RowBoldClass"}; }//if
    },
```

and the matching class

```
RowBoldClass { font-weight:bold; .....
```

Comment: could you please explain me the code. what is that rd inside the function. What should I give inside the test value ?

Comment: where should I give the rowattr ? I want to make the entire row bold or change background color.

Comment: The rowattr would be included as part of the setup of your jqGrid, the Class you assign is the part that takes care of the style applied to the row.

Comment: The TestValue is whatever value you are testing for to determine if you want the row to be in bold or have a different background color.

Comment: could you please show me a sample? I am really not aware about jqgrid setup.

Comment: @sahana: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) provide [simple demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm). @Mark: you should better rename `rd.Cell Value` to `rd.ColumnName` to have correct syntax.

Comment: @Oleg I already saw that post and my query is, where to fit in inside my grid. should I give that outside colmodel or colname? If not where should I give that?

Comment: @sahana it is outside your colmodel and colname, this is a separate part of jqGrid you are setting up, not a property of the columnModel/columnName.

Comment: @Mark I will make it and let you know the results. Thanks !!

Comment: @Mark the css part can be given inside any css file that i have given in my jsp right ?

Comment: Any CSS file that your project/page can access.

Comment: @sahana: If you opens source of [my old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm) you will see all what you need.