# JqGrid setCell properties lost when sorting column

Tags: jqgrid

Just after editing a row (mode inline) I try to change some css properties of cells according the new value.

Typically : After editing of one row all cell of this row that contains the letter "D" I update the cell with a new css property : background-color: grey (using setCell method)

For that I use inline editing :

```
grid.jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false, add:false, del:false});
grid.jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager",{edit:true, add:false, del:false, editParams: myEditParam});
```

For change the background after editing I use the method aftersavefunc

```
myEditParam :
...
    aftersavefunc: function(rowId, dataFromServer)
    {
      var rowData = $("#list").jqGrid("getRowData", rowId);
      for (var key in rowData)
      {
        if (rowData[key] == "D")
        {
          key++;
          $("#list").jqGrid("setCell",rowId, key, "", {"background-color": "#ECECEC"}  );
        }
      }
    },
...
```

This code works but unfortunatly, when I sort one column of the grid the setCell method  is not perserved ! (the cell lost it's background-color: grey)

Does it exist a better method for change the background after editing in function of the new value ?

Thx for your help ;)

Comment: Do you only want the cell value to have the CSS style after editing or is it that any row containing a cell with a certain value should have this different style?

Comment: @Mark : Effectively all containing a cell with a certain value should have this different style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to change the format/color/style of the *cell* in the column which can the value "D" then you should use `cellattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022860/315935)).

If you need to change the format/color/style of the *row* then you should use `rowattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)).

One thing is important to understand: neither `cellattr` nor `rowattr` will be called at the end of row editing. So you will still have to use `aftersavefunc` callback.

The current code of `aftersavefunc` seems me a little strange. First of all I never had requirements to mark the value in *any* column of the grid based on the value ("D" in your case). Typically one need to test only *specific* column or columns for the value and then mark the cell or mark some other cell in the row.

In any way one need typically not just add the class in the value will be "D", but *remove the class* if the value is not "D".

I modified the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935) to support inline editing (one should use double-click to start editing and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to stop editing). **[The modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAddClassAndInlineEdit.htm)** uses the following code of `aftersavefunc` additionally to `cellattr` used in the old demo:

```js
aftersavefunc: function (rowId) {
    var closed = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowId, "closed"), indexOfColumn;
    if (closed === "Yes") {
        // add CSS classes to the cell used to mark
        $(this).jqGrid("setCell", rowId, "name", "",
           "ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
    } else {
        // remove CSS classes from the cell used to mark
        indexOfColumn = getColumnIndexByName.call(this, "name");
        $(this.rows.namedItem(rowId).cells[indexOfColumn])
            .removeClass("ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
    }
}
```

Comment: My columns are construct dynamicaly from a server Web by json msg. I can work on the json for retrieving the list of column names and loop on it for apply your code no ?

Comment: @bigburgr: I am not sure what you mean. The columns could be constructed dynamically, but only one (or only some) row can have the special meaning where the value `"D"` have special meaning. So you load information about all grid columns from the server you can include in the server response additional field: the name/the names of columns which could hold `"D"`. You need test only the columns and not all columns for `"D"`. The next problem is if the user modify "D" to another value you should *remove* `background-color` CSS style from the cell.

Comment: Thx Oleg for your help I successfully use the cellattr method with a condition if(cellValue === "D") and for that the new data from the edit mode are taken into account I have put a trigger.reload in the aftersavefunc method.

Comment: @bigburgr: You are welcome! If you use `.trigger("reloadGrid")` inside of other callback function (like `aftersavefunc`) in your case then you should place `.trigger("reloadGrid")` inside of `setTimeout`. It allows jqGrid finish processing of current event (which called `aftersavefunc`) and start processing of reloadGrid after it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the Style from that event and rather move it to the more general function below. If the style isn't applied you can always trigger a refresh on the jqGrid as part of your after edit code.

The following function will examine each column cell value and if the TestValue is matching add the class to the row.

```
    rowattr: function (rd) {
           if (rd.ColumnName == TestValue) { return {"class": "RowBoldClass"}; }//if
    },
```

and the matching class

```
RowBoldClass { font-weight:bold; .....
```

My answer from [Making a row bold, changing background color - dwr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059338/making-a-row-bold-changing-background-color-dwr/16060642#16060642)

Comment: I test that ... Where do you declare your RowBlodClass ? in the style file ui.jqgrid.css ? thx for help ;)

Comment: Anywhere your project can access a CSS file, it doesn't have to be in the ui.jqgrid.css file.