# jQGrid - Change background color of grouping header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, colors

I'm using jQGrid with grouping. Each group header will have one of three possibilites: `Pending`, `Duplicate`, `Not Duplicate`.

Based on that text, I want to change the background color of my grouping header. I'm already using the `rowattr` property of jQGrid to change the background color of my grid rows, but I can't figure out how to change the grouping header color.

Here is my implementation of `rowattr`, which I believe *should* be similar to the grouping header background color:

```
gridview: true,
rowattr: function (rd) {
    alert(rd.duplicateStatusName);
    if (rd.duplicateStatusName === "Pending Review") {
        return { "class": "css_trStatusBackground_pending" };
    }
    else if (rd.duplicateStatusName === "Duplicate") {
        return { "class": "css_trStatusBackground_dup" };
    }
    else if (rd.duplicateStatusName === "Not a duplicate") {
        return { "class": "css_trStatusBackground_notdup" };
    }
},
```

Here is a screenshot of my current grid:

[image]

I want that dark gray header color to be a different color (similar to my row color) based on that text in the header.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current implementation of `groupingRender` don't allow to use some kind of `rowattr` to style the grouping headers. So You have to iterate over the groups `groupingView.groups`, test the `value` and add the css class manually inside of `loadComplete`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeBackgroundColorOfGroupingHeader.htm) demonstrates possible implementation of the approach:

[image]

The corresponding code could be the following:

```js
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["name"], // column name by which we group
    groupColumnShow: [true],
    groupCollapse: true
},
rowattr: function (rd) {
    switch (rd.name) {
    case "test1":
        return { "class": "class1" };
    case "test2":
        return { "class": "class2" };
    case "test3":
        return { "class": "class3" };
    default:
        return {};
    }
},
loadComplete: function () {
    var i, group, cssClass, headerIdPrefix = this.id + "ghead_",
        groups = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupingView").groups,
        l = groups.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        group = groups[i];
        switch (group.value) {
        case "test1":
            cssClass = "class1";
            break;
        case "test2":
            cssClass = "class2";
            break;
        case "test3":
            cssClass = "class3";
            break;
        default:
            cssClass = "";
            break;
        }
        // listghead_0_1
        if (cssClass !== "") {
            $("#" + headerIdPrefix + group.idx + "_" + i).addClass(cssClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a million Oleg!

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! If I'll find the time in the next days I'll post to trirand my suggestions how to change the code of `groupingRender` method of jqGrid to allow to apply `rowattr` to the grouping headers.

Comment: That would be great! I'm sure this is a feature most people would like to have available.