# jqGrid: Hiding a row while sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a custom sort on a few columns of data in my grid. I'm trying to hide some of the rows of data based on their value while I'm doing the sort. In the function, I have the cell value and the row object, but I don't see the row ID which is what I was going to use to hide that row of data. Is there a way to get the row ID, or is there a better way to attack hiding rows while sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid content will be reloaded during sorting. So you can use `rowattr` to set some attributes on the rows. Inside of `rowattr` callback you have access to the object which represent the data of the row. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935). It adds CSS class `myAltRowClass` to some rows based on the content from one specific column. You can do the same. You need just defines `display: none` to CSS class `myAltRowClass`. Alternatively `rowattr` callback can return `{"style": "display: none"};` on some rows.