# jqGrid Sortable Rows, only allow sorting on certain rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jqGrid working with the `SortableRows` option enabled.  Previously i had been allowing rows to always be sorted.  When the rows are dropped, then the database is updated via an ajax call.  To do this I have been using the `update` option.

Now i need to implement the sorting to NOT be allowed for certain rows.  Namely those rows who have a column value of "1" for one of the visible columns.  I have successfully blocked the ajax updating, but visually the row still gets dropped in the new location.  I need to visually revert the row to the original location.

So far I have this code, which works, but the area with the comment is where I am stuck as to how to revert the row to the previous position.

```
jQuery("#all_driver_runs").jqGrid('sortableRows', {
    update: function (ev, ui) {
        //first check the value of the 'placed_in_runs' column
        if ($('#all_driver_runs').jqGrid('getRowData', ui.item[0].id)['placed_in_run'] !== "1") { //here update the database
            if (!ui.item[0].previousSibling) {
                $.post("scripts/update_driver_run_sort.php", {
                    this_one: ui.item[0].id,
                    prev: 'none',
                    next: ui.item[0].nextSibling.id
                });
            } else if (!ui.item[0].nextSibling) {
                $.post("scripts/update_driver_run_sort.php", {
                    this_one: ui.item[0].id,
                    prev: ui.item[0].previousSibling.id,
                    next: 'none'
                });
            } else {
                $.post("scripts/update_driver_run_sort.php", {
                    this_one: ui.item[0].id,
                    prev: ui.item[0].previousSibling.id,
                    next: ui.item[0].nextSibling.id
                });
            }
        } else {
            /*
             *no DB update, and now I need to revert to previous position here ???
             */
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `sortableRows` is compatible with jQueryUI's sortable widget, you could block the rows from being sortable when you load them by adding a class to the row and then specifying it in the `items` (or `cancel`) members of the `sortableRows`' options.

So, supposing that class is `unmovable`, you could pass `".jqgrow:not(.unmovable)"` to `sortableRows`. For example:

```
$('#all_driver_runs').jqGrid('sortableRows', {
    items: ".jqgrow:not(.unmovable)",
    /* remaining options if needed */
});
```

In order to add a class to a row, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529955/highlight-row-when-the-checkbox-is-true/10531680#10531680).

Comment: That is some good stuff, thanks for the help!  Works perfectly.

Comment: I came accross a problem with this setup.  Now if you have 2 unmovable rows next to each other, then it is impossible to drop a movable row in-between them.  I would still like to be able to drop a movable row in-between 2 unmovable rows.

Comment: See the `Cancel` member. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/C58z8/). The "DSK1" columns are unsortable while the "APPR" are. Try moving the "APPR"'s around and see if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yes thanks for the help, I found that `cancel` method, and it seems to work well.  Unfortunately the JS is messing up another method when I use `cancel`... oh well

Comment: Combine this with the jqGrid `rowattr` configuration option described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/134120 and you can easily restrict dragging based on row data :)