# Disable JQGrid row based on cell value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, html-helper

I am trying to disable a row in my JQGrid. And By using HtmlHelper class the JQGrid is done for dynamic load. An example is given below as shown that

```
  public static MvcHtmlString CreateSubGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper helper,      
                                                    GridViewModel<T> model)
 {

     htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<table id=""{0}"" class=""scroll""    
       cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0""></table>", model.Id);
     htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<div id=""{0}Pager"" class=""scroll"" 
                         style=""text-align:center;""></div>", model.Id);

     htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">");
    .....
    .....
```

And My view model contains seven columns, In which the 7th column name is "IsClosed". If this column contains Yes, or any value, then the entire row should be non-editable. And I don not know how doing it. So anybody help me please.

My View Model is following,

```
public class OBRAccountViewModel 
{
    [JQGridColumn(IsHidden = true)]
    public virtual long OBRBankSeq { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(IsHidden = true)]
    public virtual long OBRSeq { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(Name = "Overseas Account No", Index = "{0}", Width = 145, IsSearch = true)]
    public virtual string OverSeasAccountNo { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(Name = Constants.DisplayName.BeneficiaryBank, Index = "{0}", Width = 130, IsSearch = true)]
    public virtual string BeneficiaryBank { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(Name = Constants.DisplayName.CurrencyCode, Index = "{0}", Width = 130, IsSearch = true)]
    public virtual string CurrencyCode { get; set; }     

    [JQGridColumn(Name = Constants.DisplayName.AccountClosureDate, Index = "{0}", Width = 130, IsSearch = true,IsEditable=true)]
    public virtual DateTime? ClosureDate { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(Name = Constants.DisplayName.AccountClosureRemarks, Index = "{0}", Width = 250, IsSearch = true, IsEditable = true)]
    public virtual string ClosureRemarks { get; set; }

    [JQGridColumn(Name = "IsClosed", Index = "{0}", Width = 250, IsSearch = true, IsEditable = true,IsHidden=false)]
    public virtual string IsClosed { get; set; }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use `rowattr` to add classes `"ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"` if `IsClosed` contains `"Yes"`. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) where I described the approach. Don't forget to use `gridview: true` option to have additional performance advantage. Look at the

```js
gridview: true,
rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (rd.IsClosed === "Yes") { // verify that the testing is correct in your case
        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
    }
}
```

If you use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then `ui.jqgrid.css` contains the CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you uses other fork on an older version of jqGrid then you should add the above role manually.

By the way you can remove from your code the part with `class=""scroll"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0""` and `class=""scroll"" style=""text-align:center;""`. The setting are deprecated since many years. jqGrid don't use the class `scroll` internally and just remove it if it is exist.

Comment: Actually, I want it in Jquery. How to do it in JQuery? Or else can you give the full sample code, then I can easily find the solution

Comment: The javascript is written in C#, So i can not get the IsClosed column's value  @Oleg

Comment: @MdAslam: [The old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) which I reference in my answer contains [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm) which demonstrates `rowattr`. Your question about jqGrid which is written in JavaScript (as plugin to jQuery) in 100%. So the usage of some server side language can follow misunderstandness only. The most possibility to include some logic in the grid you have in JavaScript only.