# jqGrid : How to add CSS class for a row with specific criteria

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

Please consider this scenario:

I have an array an I want to show it using jqGrid:

```
var arr = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "J1" , Age: 40},
        { Id: 2, Name: "J2" , Age: 50},
        { Id: 3, Name: "J3" , Age: 60},
        { Id: 4, Name: "J4" , Age: 70},
        { Id: 5, Name: "J5" , Age: 80},
    ];
```

I want to use bootstrap styles for my grid and I want to add CSS class based of some criteria for rows. For example:

```
Criteria          CSS class
----------------------------
Age >= 80          table-danger
70 <= Age < 80     table-warning
60 <= Age < 70     table-info
```

How I can add this CSS class for my grid?

Thanks

Comment: can you add your html part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `rowattr` which informs jqGrid which additional attributes (class, title, style and so on) should be assigned to the rows of the grid *during generating the rows*. An example of the callback is the following

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (item.Age >= 80) {
        return { "class": "table-danger" };
    } else if (70 <= item.Age && item.Age < 80) {
        return { "class": "table-warning" };
    } else if (60 <= item.Age && item.Age < 70) {
        return { "class": "table-info" };
    }            
}
```

See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for a code example.