# How to color column conditionally with select edit-type and without custom formatter

Tags: drop-down-menu, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I would like to color column text conditionally with select edit-type. If I use custom formatter then value get changed. Below is my code snippets which don't work,

```
    function generateEventHandlerGrid(eventsJson){
        var eventGrid = $("#eventGrid");
           eventGrid.jqGrid({
               datatype: 'local',
               data: eventsJson.eventInfo,
             jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
    colNames: ['Event Category', 'Event Creation'],
{name: 'eventCategory', index: 'eventCategory',align:"center"},
{name: 'enabled', index: 'enabled', width:"100px",align:"center",editable:true,edittype: 'select',
                 editoptions: {value: "1:Enable;0:Disable"}, formatter: function ( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
                    if (rowObject.enabled == 1){
                       var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + "red" + "' originalValue='" + rowObject.enabled + "'>" + "Enable" + "</span>";
                       return cellHtml;
                    }else{
                       var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + "green" + "' originalValue='" + rowObject.enabled + "'>" + "Disable" + "</span>";
                       return cellHtml;
                    }
                 }}],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
               height: strMinimumHeight,
               editurl: "clientArray",
               restoreAfterSelect: false,
               loadonce: true,
    }
```

How to set text color based on value without custom formatter?

Comment: It's very difficult to read the code, which you posted. By the way the code is buggy too: `colModel` is missing after `colNames`. Please include in *every question* about jqGrid the information about the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: I have posted small piece of code. It contain large code so not easy to paste whole. I am using getRowData to get back data.

Comment: How I can get my original value from custom formatter? I am new to jqgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of custom formatter is formatting of **content** of the cell. What you try to do in your current code is setting of `style` **attribute** on the outer DOM element in the cell. The best feature for that is `cellattr` callback. Thus you can still use some formatter, for example, format the *content* as date and still set some style or class, which changes attribute of the cell.

The exact list of parameters of `cellattr` callback depends from the version and the fork of jqGrid, which you use. You can try to replace `formatter` with `cellattr` with the following code

```js
cellattr: function (rowid, cellValue, rowData, cm, item) {
    return " style='color:" + (rowData.enabled == 1 ? "red" : "green") + "'";
}
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks. One more query, what to do when I want to color row with the same value? Or change background of whole row?

Comment: @DarshanShah: You are welcome! One can use `rowattr` callback function (as grid option and not inside of a column) to change attributes (colors and so on) of some rows. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) with the corresponding old [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm). Moreover, I'd recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.15.1 - the fork of jqGrid, which I develop, if you still not use it.

Comment: Yes I already found the same link and implemented and works fine. Thanks.